# How can I display steps of my php loop with Ajax? (long polling...)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, long-polling

I have a PHP server-side script which, inside a foreach loop, connects to a router through SSH and executes some configuration blocks.

```
    <?php
function apply($hostname){
    $ssh = new Net_SSH2($hostname);
    if (!$ssh->login($this->username, $this->password)) {
       exit('Login Failed');
    }
    $i = 1;
    foreach($NMConf->configuration as $conf_step){
       $ssh->write($conf_step); //Can take 5s...
       $this->ssh_errors[] = $ssh->read("#");
       echo "Step".$i." ok.. <br/>";
       $i++;
       flush();
       sleep(1);}
} ?>
```

This fonction is called by jQuery and an Ajax request...

```
$.ajax({
    url:'apply',
    type:'POST',
    cache:false,
    async:false,
    data:{},
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
      $('#myDiv').append(data); // *_*
    }   
 });
```

I would like to display into my output div the different steps, like..

```
Step 1 (working....)
```

then

```
Step 1 OK!
Step 2 (working ....)
```

and then

```
Step 1 OK!
Step 2 OK!
```

How can I do that?

I had a look on long polling stuff & reverse ajax, but it seems a bit tricky.

Any ideas!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I propose, info of stuff put in session, and try to ask php script for status

Create script which will read session

```
<?php 
         $step = $_GET["step"];
        if($_SESSION["last_step"] != $step) //just to avoid same info twice
        {
        if(isset($_SESSION['step'.$step])
           echo $_SESSION['step'.$step];
        else
        }
        else { echo '10' }; //this will tell you that next step is not executed jet  
        ?>
```

Update your existing script to put data into session when done or working on it.
Update your javascript to execute every second or time you want e.g.

```
var _int = setInterval(your_method, 1000);
```

After all steps are done just clear interval _int `clearInterval(_int)`

Comment: You're missing the most important bit though: PHP does only persist the $_SESSION contents at the end of the script, or when you tell it to do so manually. You can only do it with `session_write_close()` - I never tried opening the same session again afterwards, might turn out to be a fun experiment.

Comment: Session is valid till its active, and Same session is used between requests, so basically you can put value into session at your first request, and every other request will be able to get that data only thing that you need to make sure that your session is started for each request.

Comment: I don't understand a word of what you're saying. The point is: While the script is in progress and you continuously update $_SESSION from within one script/request, those contents will not be available in other requests/sessions, until you *persist* the session data, which is done at the end of the request.